# Appending an element at nth index

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm working on a function, which takes a vector (possibly nested vector) as input along with some quantity y and index n. Essentially the function would append y after the nth element in the vector and adjoin the remaining elements. So far I have the following written, which isn't not working as planned:

```
(defn funcs [x y n]
(concat (take (- n 1) x) (concat (take-last (- (count x) n) y))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return a vector as the final value, you'll have to concatenate your vectors using `into` (in time linear in the size of the right operand) or [`core.rrb-vector`](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector)'s `catvec` (logarithmic time, but the resulting vector will be somewhat slower overall).

As for the actual implementation, assuming you want to go with core.rrb-vector:

```
(require '[clojure.core.rrb-vector :as fv])

(defn append-after-nth [x y n]
  (fv/catvec (fv/subvec x 0 n) y (fv/subvec x n)))
```

Comment: so much better than what my naive solution would have been!

Comment: The dependency `[org.clojure/core.rrb-vector "${version}"]` is giving me troubles. It says there is an illegal character in path at index 59. This is the first time I've ever experienced such issues with lein deps.

Comment: You need to provide the actual version you want in lieu of "${version}", e.g. "0.0.10".